# Why my crawler neither fetches any data nor throws any error

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have made a crawler to parse the name of products from Amazon but when i run my crawler it neither brings any result nor shows any error. So far I know, Xpaths are okay. Can't find out any mistakes I've made already. Hope there is somebody to look into it.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def Startpoint():
    url = "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers/zgbs"
    response = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//ul[@id="zg_browseRoot"]')
    for title in titles:
        items=title.xpath('.//li/a/@href')
        for item in items:
            Endpoint(item)

def Endpoint(links):
    response = requests.get(links)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="a-section a-spacing-none p13n-asin"]')
    for title in titles:
        try :
            Name=title.xpath('.//div[@class="p13n-sc-truncated-hyphen p13n-sc-truncated"]/text()')[0]
            print(Name)
        except:
            continue

Startpoint()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get any errors because you have a try - except block in your script .
If you want to display errors , change this :

```
except:
    continue
```

to :

```
except Exception as e : 
    print(e.message)
    continue
```

Note :

It's best to have an except block for every expected exception ( keyerror, valueerror, etc ) ,  if you plan to handle those cases separately .

Thanks to @David Metcalfe for this suggestion

Comment: I can't recall or locate the PEP, but I'm sure it's mentioned somewhere as well how it's highly ill-advised to have a catch-all `except` for reasons OP is now seeing. Might be worth a mention in the answer if you can locate it.

Comment: @David Metcalfe if you mean have an `except` for multiple possible  exceptions , i agree . This post is intented to help the OP debug his script , it is not a best practice example